# Calculate $i^{\log(−)}$ (principal value)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I am working on a complex number problem and need some guidance on how to calculate the principal value of the expression "$i^{\log(-i)}$". I understand that the principal value of a complex logarithm is the one with an argument in the range $(-π, π]$, but I'm not sure how to apply this concept to the given expression.

To be more specific, I'm looking for a step-by-step explanation or a mathematical approach to find the principal value of this complex exponentiation. Any insights, suggestions, or formulas that can help me compute this value would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Are you aware how to evaluate $\log(-i)$ on the principal branch?  Equivalently, do you know how to write $-i$ in the polar form $r e^{i\theta}$ where $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$?  (at the moment, I don't have a sufficient picture of what you know to write anything appropriate up)

Comment: no, I couldn't catch it. Can you help?

Comment: Note the parenthetical I added to my comment after your initial response.  I know some people on here might be fine without seeing something more from you, but I don't personally feel comfortable answering questions unless I have a concept of where you are in your understanding.  Are you at least aware of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Euler%27s_formula&oldid=1180628775)?

Comment: yes, I know Euler's formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by computing the principal branch of $\log(-i)$:
$$
\log(-i)=\log(e^{-i\pi/2})=-i\frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{1}
$$
Now we do the same for $i^{\log(-i)}$:
$$
i^{\log(-i)}=i^{-i\pi/2}=e^{-i(\pi/2)\log(i)}=e^{-i(\pi/2)\log(e^{i\pi/2})}=
e^{-i(\pi/2)(i\pi/2)}=e^{\pi^2/4}. \tag{2}
$$